# Update AngularJS component when bindings change

Tags: angularjs, components

I have a parent component `<lookup-table></lookup-table>`, which has a the following template:

```
<td>
    <whois domain="{{ $ctrl.query }}" extension="{{ ext.name }}"></whois>
</td>
```

The `<whois></whois>` component is a s follows:

```
angular.
module('app.components.whois').
component('whois', {
  template: "Whois: {{ $ctrl.domain + '.' + $ctrl.extension + ' = ' + $ctrl.whois }}",
  controller: [
    function WhoisController() {
      this.whois = 'http://'+this.domain+'.'+this.extension;
    }
  ],
  bindings: {
    domain: '@',
    extension: '@'
  }
});
```

When parent `$ctrl.domain` or `$ctrl.extension` changes, `<whois></whois>` component is updated except for variable $ctrl.whois.

I understand that this is due to `$ctrl.whois` being set only once, when the controller function is executed.

How can I make `$ctrl.whois` update when bindings change ?

Comment: You need to look at the $onChanges(changesObj) hook for components https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component. This will allow you to check whenever domain or extension changes. Then you can update this.whois

Comment: Thanks ! That worked like charm :) If you post an answer I will be happy to mark it as resolver.

Comment: Done. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the $onChanges(changesObj) hook for components docs.angularjs.org/guide/component. This will allow you to check whenever domain or extension changes. Then you can update this.whois.